# funtion return not passing through to another function

Tags: python

i'm trying to pass the variable which is a user input from one function through to the next function, im getting the error that the function initiateWD is missing the gamecode argument

```
def joinLobby():
    print('Enter game code:')
    gamecode = str(input().upper())
    return gamecode

def initiateWD(gamecode):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.set_window_size(600, 500)
    driver.get("https://jklm.fun/{}".format(gamecode))
```

Comment: How exactly are you passing the argument? Something like `initiateWD(joinLobby())` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share how you called initiateWD function.So based on your question,here is my solution --

```
def joinLobby():
    print('Enter game code:')
    gamecode = str(input().upper())
    return gamecode

def initiateWD(gamecode):
    driver = 
       webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.set_window_size(600, 500)
    driver.get("https://jklm.fun/{}".format(gamecode))

initiateWD(joinLobby())
```

Here joinLobby function is called and pass to initiateWD as a parameter.The function called with initiateWD(joinLobby) - here  the joinLobby function passing as parameter ,so in initiateWD you have to called joinLobby() first to get the gamecode